# Can't import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration and androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration and androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI into my main activity.

Here is my main activity:

```
package com.example.cyticketclient;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.navigation_sales,
                R.id.navigation_messages,
                R.id.navigation_forum,
                R.id.navigation_profile).build();

    }
}
```

I am getting the error

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'ui'
```

How do I get androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration and androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI to import?

Here is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.cyticketclient"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime:2.3.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Classes in `androidx.navigation.ui` are in the `navigation-ui` dependency as per the [Navigation declaring dependencies](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#declaring_dependencies)

```
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.0'
```

Comment: Note that you'll need to replace the `navigation-runtime` dependency with `navigation-fragment` if you want to use `<fragment>` destinations in your navigation graph (`navigation-fragment` has a dependency on `navigation-runtime`, so you wouldn't need to explicitly declare a dependency on `navigation-runtime` if you have a dependency on `navigation-fragment`).

Comment: For Kotlin:
implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.7.6")